# how to iterate through lists vertically?

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, python-3.x, collections

I have multiple lists to work with. What I'm trying to do is to take a certain index for every list(in this case index 1,2,and 3), in a vertical column. And add those vertical numbers to an empty list.

```
line1=[1,2,3,4,5,5,6]
line2=[3,5,7,8,9,6,4]
line3=[5,6,3,7,8,3,7]

vlist1=[]
vlist2=[]
vlist3=[]
```

expected output

```
Vlist1=[1,3,5] 
Vlist2=[2,5,6]
Vlist3=[3,7,3]
```

Answer (score 7):

Having variables with numbers in them is often a design mistake. Instead, you should probably have a nested data structure. If you do that with your `line1`, `line2` and `line3` lists, you'd get a nested list:

```
lines = [[1,2,3,4,5,5,6],
         [3,5,7,8,9,6,4],
         [5,6,3,7,8,3,7]]
```

You can then "transpose" this list of lists with `zip`:

```
vlist = list(zip(*lines)) # note the list call is not needed in Python 2
```

Now you can access the inner lists (which in are actually tuples this now) by indexing or slicing into the transposed list.

```
first_three_vlists = vlist[:3]
```

Answer (score 1):

in python 3 `zip` returns a generator object, you need to treat it like one:

```
from itertools import islice

vlist1,vlist2,vlist3 = islice(zip(line1,line2,line3),3)
```

But really you should [keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).  Use a list-of-lists data structure, and if you need to transpose it just do:

```
list(zip(*nested_list))
Out[13]: [(1, 3, 5), (2, 5, 6), (3, 7, 3), (4, 8, 7), (5, 9, 8), (5, 6, 3), (6, 4, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pythons [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function, index accordingly.

```
>>> line1=[1,2,3,4,5,5,6]
>>> line2=[3,5,7,8,9,6,4]
>>> line3=[5,6,3,7,8,3,7]
>>> zip(line1,line2,line3)
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 5, 6), (3, 7, 3), (4, 8, 7), (5, 9, 8), (5, 6, 3), (6, 4, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your input lists into a list.  Then to create the ith vlist, do something like this:

```
vlist[i] = [];
for l in list_of_lists:
    vlist[i].append(l[i])
```